# AWK if inside for loop

Tags: bash, awk

I am using a one liner awk to format a file in html

```
(awk -v var="$tLen" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "<td align=center ROWSPAN=" var ">" $i"</td>"; } END {}' $part1file ) >> "$output"
```

output:

```
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>921</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>29128</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>4f9ea...b6c4a</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>11/09/2015_13:09:44</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>1</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>20</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>4</td>
```

I need to return this:

```
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>921</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>29128</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>4f9ea...b6c4a<br/>11/09/2015_13:09:44</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>1</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>0</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>20</td>
<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>4</td>
```

Just on the end of the 5th line instead on closing the tag with  insert a 
 then the next row data  and then close with

I've tried something like

```
(awk -v var="$tLen" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i==6)  print "<br/>"; else print "<td align=center ROWSPAN=" var ">" $i"; if (i==5) print ""; else  print "</td>";  } END {}' $part1file ) >> "$output"
```

But it doesn't work. I seek help to make this if conditions to work inside the awk any light on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your sample input data as well.

Comment: What about that "doesn't work"? (I mean it won't get you the output you want but it should "work" in the sense that it does something different for field six.) It won't do what you want because you'll have *already* output the trailing `</td>` for field five by the time you get to field six (which should be your hint).

Comment: Why are you using the sub-shell?  It doesn't seem to be necessary in the context shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding braces around the body of the `for`.

```
awk -v var="$tLen" \
   'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; }
    {   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        {
            if (i == 6) print "<br/>"; else print "<td align=center ROWSPAN=" var ">" $i";
            if (i == 5) print ""; else print "</td>";
        }
    }
   ' $part1file >> "$output"
```

Comment: Can you show what you mean?  Probably over several lines; one-liner is a term of opprobrium when the line gets too long, as it will in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

another awk

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          v=$i;
          if(i==5){
             v=$5"<br/>"$6;i++
          } 
          print "<td align=center ROWSPAN=4>" v "</td>"
       }
      }'
```

print value in given format, which is the field in order, except for 5 where it's a combination of 5 and 6.

I'm not sure why you need the variable var or OFS to be tab.